# How do I get the particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation $u_{x} + u_{y} = 3$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So far, I'm easily able to derive the solution of the homogeneous equation $u_{x}+u_{y}=0$ using separation of variables. That is, since $u$ is constant on the line $y = x + C$, it follows that $u(x,y)=f(y-x)$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: It makes sense to guess a particular solution considering you already know the solution to the homogeneous problem. How about trying $$u = f(x-y) + Ax + Ay$$ considering you need to differentiate $u$ once for both $x$ and $y$?

Comment: So using $u=f(x-y)+Ax+Ay$, I get $u_{x}=A$ and $u_{y}=A$. Does that simply mean that $u_{x}+u_{y}=2A$ and so $A = 3/2$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But note that this is just _one_ of many guesses.